# Better algorithm to find a net for a polyhedron.

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computer-science, polyhedra

I found out recently that whether or not every convex polyhedron has a net is an open problem. However, assuming that they do, I was wondering if there were particularly useful ideas that could **reduce the time/cases to check** to automatedly generate a net of a given convex polyhedron (whether the faces are all regular polygons).

To be clear, I understand that whether or not any search algorithm will actually terminate with a success is open but I wonder if there are easily computable properties of a edge-cut graph or something similar that allow you to check if a potential net will overlap with itself without having to abstractly draw it in the program and then check (or any other similar speedup).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by a "net" in this context : this word has different meanings ? The fact that no comments have been made for 4 hours probably mean that you haven't been precise enough. In particular you do not say how your convex polyhedron is given ... By a set of affine inequations $2x-3y+z \leq 5$, etc ? May be an example would help ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: I mean a self-overlapping unfolding in the sense of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Unfolding.html

Comment: And surely everyone has seen/made a net of a cube in their time? The polyhedron is almost certainly given as a set of faces and connections between them (with the secret understanding that a face connected to $n$ others is a regular $n$-gon).

Comment: I am confused about the role of _regular_ polygons in this question. The list of convex polyhedra in which all faces are regular polygons is well known -- they are called the Johnson solids (together with the Platonic solids and the Archimedean solids, which are often considered disjoint from the Johnson solids). Every such polyhedron _does_ have a non-overlapping net. Furthermore, for all of the Platonic solids and most but not all of the Archimedean solids, _every_ unfolding has no overlap. So it seems the question is primarily of interest for polyhedra with non-regular faces.

Comment: That being said, Demaine and O'Rourke's book "Geometric Unfolding Algorithms" does have a survey of known unfolding algorithms, based primarily on Schlickenrieder's thesis. One algorithm described, "Steepest-Edge-Unfold," succeeded on all polyhedra in a test database of thousands of polyhedra testing no more than six spanning trees of cuts for any individual polyhedron.